# Is it possible to turn off the drawerBackground screen overlap?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

When open app on mobile i need to have a fully functional drawerNavigator (drawerType: front, and hide on swipe and on press on outside of screen close the drawer). But in tablet version i need to have always opened drawerNavigation with drawerType: slide and the same time have opportunity to press on current screen. How can i make it?

expected display of the screen
[image]

how my app work now 
[image]

**Expected Behavior**

- I expect that there is a solution that will make it possible to disable the substrate as an background view

**Your Environment**

"react-navigation": "4.0.10",
 "react-navigation-drawer": "2.3.2",
 "react-navigation-stack": "1.10.3",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some information inside source files in this library

> We don't want the user to be able to press through the overlay when
>   drawer is open One approach is to adjust the pointerEvents based on
>   the progress But we can also send the overlay behind the screen, which
>   works, and is much less code.

So, looks like your case is not executable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already saw this is information, but not fully understand what the developers meant by the words: _But we can also send the overlay behind the screen, which works, and is much less code._

It seems that it may turn out to be what I want to implement. But I didn't find any examples with **drawerType: back**. 

Maybe if we use **drawerType: back** and add a padding on the screen, or/and reduce width of drawerContainer, we will be able to implement expected behavior.
I tried many options, but none of them worked. :(